# Get Android Device and OS Info in Firemonkey

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

I know how to get app version, package name, udid for both Android and iOS
But for iOS I can get more info.

Code below returns model name, device name, os type and os version:

```
string(Device.model.UTF8String);//Model name
string(Device.name.UTF8String);//Device name
string(Device.systemName.UTF8String);//Os type
string(Device.systemVersion.UTF8String);//Os version
```

Is it also possible to get this info For Android? I'm currently working in Delphi 10 Seattle.

Comment: Can you try this module: http://fire-monkey.ru/topic/1762-deviceinfo-modul-dlia-polucheniia-informatcii-o-devaise/

Comment: @kami It's hard to read russian, but only code i see is for iOS

Comment: Do not read russian :) Read code in first attachment DeviceInfo.zip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found what i'm looking for. With the following code i can get model name of android phone and android version:

```
JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.MODEL);//Model name
JStringToString(TJBuild_VERSION.JavaClass.RELEASE);//Os Version
```

Comment: what must you add to uses clause to have this working ?

Comment: @user763539 you need Android.Helpers, Androidapi.JNI.Os and Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes

Comment: Any idea why the second line (and all properties of `TJBuild_VERSION`) crash on both devices I tried? The first line works.

Comment: @maf-soft probably depends on Rad Studio version and Android version. This ticket is 5 years old so there have probably been some changes.